# What is preventing malicious miners stealing data to steal smart contract rewards?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, calldata

The motivation for this question is roughly along the lines of a puzzle contract -- whoever submits the correct solution to the puzzle gets a reward from the contract.

I'm guessing that the 'thing' in a transaction that is actually signed is a hash of the `from:` and `to:` addresses (the sender and recipient addresses of the transaction in question), and `value` too.. This would prevent malicious miners from just changing all `to:` addresses to ones owned by themselves, and mining blocks transferring random people's money to them.

Is the `data` field included in the hash too? Is it also sent in the clear? Is there anything 'binding' the signature/original sender and the data together? If not, is there anything else preventing puzzle solutions submitted to the contract being intercepted and resubmitted by the lucky guy mining the block?

Answer (score 2):

All of the data in the transaction is signed and visible to everyone, including the miners.

A good way of preventing miners from stealing solutions is to have the person first submit the hash of the solution, then later submit the actual solution once the hash has already been mined.

Comment: Thanks, yeah in this case H(solution||address) or just H(solution) should work, but it'll double the comms overhead and number of blocks that the contract execution requires, so I was just checking whether some similar magic didn't occur automatically -- unlikely i know ! :)